# How to make colorful tab or add some outputText after tabs in primefaces?

Tags: css, primefaces, xhtml

[image]

I have two tabs in tabView and i need another one with as shown in attachment. It can also be any outputText, but it doesn work with . Also the part of text should be black and another red.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem. I've been trying a lot of examples, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the decision with this:

```
<p:tab disabled="true"
        titleStyle="font-weight: bold; opacity: 0.9; background-color: #b2bcbe;" >
        <f:facet name="title">
            <h:outputText value="black text" style="color: black;"/>
            <h:outputText value="red text" style="color: red;"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:tab>
```